# Проблемы с авторизацией ulogin.ru

Tags: php, ulogin

Сразу к делу. После авторизации попадаешь на главную страницу сайта(так и должно быть), Но сайт считает тебя не авторизованным.Т.Е (так же остается кнопка зарегистрироваться и т.д)
В чем может быть проблема?

```
<!-- Вход пользователя -->
<div id="account">{if $user}
    <span id="username">
        Здравствуйте,
        <a href="user">{$user->name}</a>{if $group->discount>0},
        ваша скидка — {$group->discount}%{/if}
    </span>
    <a id="logout" href="user/logout">выйти</a>
    {else}
    <a id="register" href="user/register">Регистрация</a>
    <a id="login" href="user/login">Вход</a>
    или


    <script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
    <a href="#" id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=window;fields=first_name,last_name;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fberi-dari.org"><img src="http://ulogin.ru/img/button.png" width=187 height=30 alt="МультиВход"/></a>

    {/if}

</div>
<!-- Вход пользователя (The End)-->

    // Вход через ULogin
elseif(isset($_POST['token']))
{
    $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $data = json_decode($s, true);
    if (isset($data['uid'])) {
        $name = $data['first_name'].' '.$data['last_name'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $password = md5($data['uid'].'9d6e1c88e1c559e682b86a2713b15484');//пришлось свою сок добавить, так как у class Users private $salt

        //проверяем есть ли в БД такой емейл
        $this->db->query('SELECT count(*) as count, id FROM __users WHERE email=?', $email) $user_exists = $this->db->result();

        if($user_id = $this->users->check_password($email, $password))
        {
            $user = $this->users->get_user($email);
            if($user->enabled)
            {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                header('Location: '.$this->config->root_url);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->design->assign('error', 'user_disabled');
            }
        }
        elseif($user_exists->count)
        {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_exists->id;
            header('Location: '.$this->config->root_url);
        }
        else
        {
            $user_id = $this->users->add_user(
                array('name'=>$name,
                    'email'=>$email,
                    'password'=>$password,
                    'enabled'=>1)
            );
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            header('Location: '.$this->config->root_url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print_r($_SESSION); // Посмотрите сессию, все ли параметры занесены? Если да, то на главной смотрите её и выводите пользователю скрытую от гостей информацию

Comment: пользователя нигде нет...ни в сессии не в бд.умные люди сказали нужно исправить это fields=first_name,last_name; на это fields=first_name,last_name,email;....ну тоесть дописать мыло так как оно является обязательным....но проблему это не решило.я так понимаю в $user->name ничего не передается.....а вот как сделать чтобы передавалось имя.например с вк